# How to split array into elements based JAVA streams

Tags: java, arrays

I need to split array into following way using java streams API

```
int [] arr = {1,3,5,8,9}
```

into

```
{1,3,5}, {3,5,8}, {5,8,9}
```

Comment: You might need to use a custom collector or in general by stateful.

Comment: ou might need to start trying first. This is not a coding service. And then, see how to [ask]. You don't give any explanation on what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Thanks AxeIH , I can do it form for loop using traditional way , but I have no idea how to do with stream

Answer (score 0):

to do the same we can also use the grouping by as shown below:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class SplitList
{
    // Generic function to split a list in Java 8
    public static<T> List[] split(List<T> list)
    {
        int midIndex = (list.size() - 1) / 2;

        List<List<T>> lists = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> list.indexOf(s) > midIndex))
                                .values());

        // return an array containing both lists
        return new List[] {lists.get(0), lists.get(1)};
    }

    // Program to split a list in Java
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

        // split list into two
        List[] lists = split(list);

        System.out.println(lists[0]);
        System.out.println(lists[1]);
    }
}
```

for further queries check the link:-
http://www.techiedelight.com/split-list-two-sublists-java/

Comment: Thanks , but I need out put is [A, B, C] , [B, C, D], [C,D,E]

Comment: I don't believe this deserve two answers. You only changed the `collect` method.

Comment: i have given the answers just in refrence to questions well you are right with the refrence to just change the collect method.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include both solution. Also you should EXPLAIN your code. Code only answers aren't the best answers. Especially if you link most of the solution (link can die). See [answer] about that.

Comment: i have given just an idea to the question depending on which he can make his code and regarding your suggestion to improve the answering way i will surely try to change that way.